# I just want it to print it for example addition table([2,5,-3,7]) returns [[3,6,-2,8],[4,7,-1,9],[5,8,0,10]] . Pls tell me how

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def addition_table20(numbers):
    #numbers = []
    row = 3
    col = len(numbers)
    i = 0
    for x in range(1, row):
        for i in range(0, col + 1):
            if i <= len(numbers):
                print([numbers[i] + 1, numbers[i] +2,numbers[i] + 3])
                i += 1

            #if i >= len(numbers):
            #   print()
            #else:
            ##  i += 1


    #return numbers

print(addition_table20([2,5,-3,7]))
```

I can't understand how to print it like this  `[[3,6,-2,8],[4,7,-1,9],[5,8,0,10]`.
**The question**: Implement a function addition table(numbers) that takes a list of n numbers and returns an n × 3 table where the first row contains the given numbers plus 1, the second row contains the given numbers plus 2, and the third row contains the given numbers plus 3.
**Example**: calling addition table(`[2,5,-3,7]`) returns `[[3,6,-2,8],[4,7,-1,9],[5,8,0,10]]`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please [edit] your post to clarify, in words, what you are trying to do, and what exactly you need our help with. Consult the [ask] and [mcve] pages for details on how to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
a = [2,5,-3,7]
row = 3

result = [[x+i for x in a] for i in range(1, row+1)]
print(result)
```

The output will be:

```
[[3, 6, -2, 8], [4, 7, -1, 9], [5, 8, 0, 10]]
```

Comment: uh I need to make a function for it . sorry if I didn't mention that

Comment: @coderX well, you can definitely use this solution and move that into a function...

Answer (score 0):

just a simpler way to the answer posted by @lorenzozane

```
 #function defination
    def cal():
        
        a = [2,3,-4]
        row =5 
    
        for x in range(0,row):
            result = []
            for i in a :
                result.append(i+1)
            print(result)
            a = result
   #function call
 cal()
```

the output would be :

```
[3, 4, -3]
[4, 5, -2]
[5, 6, -1]
[6, 7, 0]
[7, 8, 1]
```